# Create github issue from travis.yaml

Tags: github, travis-ci, github-api, travis-ci-cli

I am looking for some ways to create a github issue from travis. 
I am calling some scripts in `travis.yaml` file and I need to create a github issue when travis is executed. I came across documents on calling github APIS using curl command.

Eg: `curl -u $username -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"title":"'$title'", "body":"'$body'"}' https://api.github.com/repos/$username/$repo_name/issues`

Instead of `username` , since the build is triggered via travis, should I use github tokens? Is there any environment variable available which represents github token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Create a github token using the github API and add that as ENV variable to your Travis CI settings.

This token can be used to perform the curl operation in travis shell script.

Helpful link : https://blogs.infosupport.com/accessing-githubs-rest-api-with-curl/